# String to date Format in j2me

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have a String  `Wed, 22 Aug 2012 06:29:31 +0530` like this, now I want to convert this String to a date format and I need to display day an date `Wed, 22 Aug 2012` like this and eliminating other remaining String?

I need to display the date on my LWUIT form Screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String date = "Wed, 22 Aug 2012 06:29:31 +0530";
String shortDate = date.substring(0, 16);
```

Comment: This doesn't account for i18n, it will work great as long as the date is in English

Comment: I agree with @ShaiAlmog that this is not the best approach, but I just suggested the code based on the question needs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write the code manually by using the methods in `java.util.Calendar`, we did some formatters and localization API's in Codename One so you can look at our code for reference or just move to [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/).

Answer (score 2):

For this date formate "date_posted":"2012-04-19T16:45:33+01:00" i use the following code. You can customize it for your needs.

```
 try {
                String dateString = date_posted;
                String[] dateArray = Util.split(dateString, "T");
                String[] date = Util.split(dateArray[0], "-");
                String[] time = Util.split(dateArray[1], ":");
            Calendar calStart = Calendar.getInstance();
            calStart.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(date[1]) - 1);
            calStart.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(date[2]));
            calStart.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(date[0]));
            calStart.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(time[0]));
            calStart.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(time[1]));
            calStart.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            Date postDate = calStart.getTime();

            post_time = postDate.getTime();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.err("fromJSON", ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I use something like this :

```
String getDateString(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);

    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    return new String(/*Any format you need*/);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific method in j2me to convert string to date. So, that is **not possible** at all.

Comment: this can't be considered an answer, since it is possible, not with a predefined method but there are alternatives